# Generating a new surface with a filled square and text string in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, rectangles, pygame-surface

I am creating a class which shall return me a surface with a square and the text as displayed below:

[image: surface]

The square (currently) shows the user's colour for the game and text is player name. I'll `blit` these surfaces on the screen after calculating the positions from an array of similar surfaces.

I'm able to generate the `text` surface easily. I don't want to pass the screen surface to the class for `pygame.draw.rect`; but rather, create the rectangle separately; merge the rectangle and text surface and then return this grouped surface. My current class definition is simply:

```python
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import font as pyfont, event as pyevent, display as pydisplay
from sys import exit

class Info:
    GRAY = ( 214, 171, 127 )
    def __init__( self, name, colour ):
        pyfont.init()
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
        self.font = pyfont.Font( None, 36 )

    def generate( self ):
        text = self.font.render( self.name, True, self.GRAY )
        # The rectangle surface to be drawn here
        return text
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nothing. I can create the rectangles if I pass the screen surface as a parameter to the class, but as I mentioned in the question; I don't want to do that. I want to leave all the positional calculations for later. I've also looked at the [`subsurface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) function; but again, I'd have to calculate my placement positions before initialising the class.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of more reading of pygame docs, I've updated the class to be something like:

```python
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import font as pyfont, event as pyevent, display as pydisplay
from sys import exit

class Info:
    GRAY = ( 214, 171, 127 )
    def __init__( self, surface, name, colour ):
        pyfont.init()
        self.surface = surface
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
        self.font = pyfont.Font( None, 36 )

    def generate( self ):
        t = pygame.Rect( 5, 5, 32, 32 )
        pygame.draw.rect( self.surface, self.colour, t, 0 )
        text = self.font.render( self.name, True, self.GRAY )
        return self.surface.blit( text, (50, 5) )
```

and it can be used as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = pygame.Rect( 50, 50, 250, 100 )
    screen = pydisplay.set_mode( (1024, 576) )
    pydisplay.set_caption( "Title goes" )
    srf = screen.subsurface( x )
    x = Info( srf, "hjpotter92", (230, 150, 51) )
    c = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen.fill( (255, 255, 255) )
    while True:
        pydisplay.update()
        c.tick( 1 )
        print x.generate()
        for event in pyevent.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                exit( 0 )
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    exit( 0 )
```

But it is a dirty/foul solution to the problem, and generates something like:

[image: current-output]

I'm open to changes to the current design. Otherwise I'd have to keep calculating the positions for further instances of `Info` class beforehand.